# Upload a photo to telegram API using Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to send a photo (or other type of files like Video or Document).
How can i upload a photo (from local) to telegram?

```php
$client->request('POST', 'sendPhoto', [
    'query' => [
        'chat_id'=> 'xxxxx',
        'photo'=> fopen('img.png', 'r')
    ]
]);
```

But this not work for me.
How can i send a photo from my local system to telegram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`multipart`](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart) if you want guzzle to post the file:

```php
$client->request('POST', 'sendPhoto', [
  'multipart' => [
    [ 'name' => 'chat_id', 'contents' => 'xxxxx'],
    [
      'name' => 'photo',
      'contents' => fopen('img.png', 'r')
    ]
  ]
]);
```

If you have a lot of parameters, you could use a helper function that maps your aassociative array:

```php
function toMultiPart(array $arr) {
  $result = [];
  array_walk($arr, function($value, $key) use(&$result) {
    $result[] = ['name' => $key, 'contents' => $value];
  });
  return $result;
}

$client->request('POST', 'sendPhoto', [
  'multipart' => toMultiPart([
    'chat_id'=> 'xxxxx',
    'photo'=> fopen('img.png', 'r')
  ])
});
```

Comment: Thanks. but it's a little hard to convert every parameter to an array of 'name' and 'contents'. is there any other ways?

Comment: @Exind you could use a small helper function that transforms the array for you, i've updated my answer with a small example